# Different Versions of one page

Tags: seo

Is there any drawback to having different versions of the same page? 
For example: https://sdsportsandspine.com/online-forms.html?ada=1 and https://sdsportsandspine.com/online-forms.html

Before we had responsive websites, we were able to force a desktop site using ?desktopRedirect=1 but I am wondering if the ada formatting that is being used is negative for seo in any way.

Comment: Sorry but this question has been asked in various forms many times on Pro Webmasters. We have questions and answers regarding similar pages, exact pages served on multiple urls and so on. Please use the search feature.

Comment: I did use the search function, didn't find anything that was similar and then asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same page, at least that's how a search engine would see it.

I'm assuming your web server is configured to process online-forms.html as a PHP (or some other script) script. In which case yes, it is the same script, but no, it's not the same URL.

Presumably, the value of the 'ada' variable renders different contents dependent on the value, hence it's a different page.